# enzyme mount component has error in i18n

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs, i18next

I use i18n in my component and wrapped in I18nextProvider like this:

```
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <I18nextProvider i18n={mockI18n}>
      <Component initState={initData} />
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
```

The mockI18n is:

```
const mockI18n = {
  t(k) {
    return k;
  },
  on() {
  },
  getFixedT(k) {
    return (k) => k;
  },
  loadNamespaces(arg) {
    return (arg) => arg;
  }
};
```

This works fine when I use shallow. However, I want to test a onChange function, so I need to find the element and simulate click event in a nested sub component. The shallow is not able to find the element, so I want to try out mount, but wen I use mount it gives me error:

```
ReferenceError: t is not defined

      16 |             name="user_id"
    > 17 |             label={t('User ID')}
      18 |             type="text"
      19 |             value={this.state.user_id}
```

What should I do to apply i18n to sub component? Or how to test this.props.onChange when use shallow?

Comment: What's `I18nextProvider` coming from and what it does with `i18n`?

Comment: I18nextProvider is a package, I import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';

Answer (score 0):

I think inside the component you need to get the `t` function inside the component that uses the translation.

```
const { t } = props;
```

...

Only then you can call the `t` function.

```
    label={t('User ID')}
```

https://react.i18next.com/getting-started.html